# Styling required .svg images

Tags: reactjs, svg

I have a folder full of svg icons that I need to style based off some dynamic variable. This is what I want to do:

```
      <img
       name="survey"
       src={require('../../../images/silhouette.svg')}
       alt="Owl"
       style={{ fill: someDynamicColor }}/>
```

The problem is the `.svg` is not respecting my "fill" option. Is there anyway to dynamically style a required svg image?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can only alter the fill of an SVG if its code is directly in your HTML. If you have the SVG locally and are using it's file path as the `src` for an `<img>` tag, you can't change the fill.